# How should I use AddHandler in cppwinrt with Handler objects?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

In the C++/WinRT reflection, the API [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler?view=winrt-19041) is defined as

`UIElement::AddHandler(Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEvent const& routedEvent, Windows::foundation::IInspectable const& handler, bool handledEventsToo) const`

But the handlers seems to only inherit from `IUnknown`. For example, this is the declaration of [KeyEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyeventhandler?view=winrt-19041):

`struct KeyEventHandler : Windows::foundation::IUnknown`

What is the solution for registering an event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like we need to call `box_value(handler)` which will convert it into an `IInspectable`. It is not obvious at all, and you cannot find any samples on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on iohanson's answer, yes, the delegate needs to be boxed up. WinRT delegates are `IUnknown`, not `IInspectable`. `AddHandler` expects to get an `IReference<T>` where `T` is a delegate for a `RoutedEvent`.

I opened an issue on cppwinrt to see if we can get some more helpful overloads, since cppwinrt we don't do the same magic boxing CX users enjoyed.
https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/776